# objective-c custom UITabBarItem @2x

Tags: objective-c, uitabbaritem, retina-display

is it possible to assign a highres custom uitabbaritem image?

```
    UIImage *img;
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabIcon51@2x.png"];
    self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"more" image:img tag:5];
```

this doesnt work. is there a workaround, or even better an officel link / solution for this usecase?

thanks
alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using imageNamed, you can exclude the @2x.  The way imageNamed works is that if you're on a high res device it automatically loads the @2x file if it exists, otherwise it loads the regular file.